# Cannot add an item to a List in a constructor of a user control's base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kentico

I seem to be getting a null reference error when I try to add an item to a list in the constructor of my CustomCheckoutProcess class.  This class is inherited by a user control's class, so its default constructor is called when the control's constructor is called (I believe that's how it works).

Here's the relevant parts of the class definition for the checkout process (error seems to be line 12 - marked with a comment on line 11):

```
public class CustomShoppingCart : ShoppingCart {

    private List<CheckoutProcessArgument> checkoutProcessArguments = List<CheckoutProcessArgument>();

    public CustomShoppingCart()
    {
        GetBaseCartSteps();

        CheckoutProcessArgument stepTwoArg = new CheckoutProcessArgument("Step2", new Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"));

        // when I comment this line out, everything works fine
        checkoutProcessArguments.Add(stepTwoArg);

        BuildCheckoutProcess();
    }

    private void GetBaseCartSteps()
    {
        baseCartSteps = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // iterate through base cart's steps and grab name/index pairs
        foreach (CheckoutProcessStepInfo step in this.CheckoutProcessSteps)
        {
            baseCartSteps.Add(step.Name, step.StepIndex);
        }
    }

    private bool CartContains(Guid productGuid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ShoppingCartInfoObj.CartItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ShoppingCartInfoObj.CartItems[i].SKU.SKUGUID == productGuid)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void BuildCheckoutProcess()
    {
        // create a list of ints to dynamically add or remove the indexes of the base cart's steps
        List<int> steps = new List<int>();


        if (checkoutProcessArguments != null)
        {
            // add steps if they are specified in the arguments list
            foreach (CheckoutProcessArgument argument in checkoutProcessArguments)
            {
                if (CartContains(argument.ProductGUID))
                {
                    int stepIndexToAdd;

                    baseCartSteps.TryGetValue(argument.StepName, out stepIndexToAdd);
                    steps.Add(stepIndexToAdd);
                }
            }
        }

        // sort the steps so that they'll be in the correct order
        steps.Sort();

        customSteps = new int[steps.Count];

        customSteps = steps.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And here's the struct that I'm using to create arguments for a custom checkout process:

```
public struct CheckoutProcessArgument
{
    private string stepName;
    private Guid productGUID;

    public string StepName { get { return stepName; } }

    public Guid ProductGUID { get { return productGUID; } }

    public CheckoutProcessArgument(string stepName, Guid productGuid)
    {
        this.stepName = stepName;
        this.productGUID = productGuid;
    }

}
```

Here's the stack trace for the error I recieve:

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Stack Trace: 
at CustomShoppingCart..ctor()
...
```

Problem is, I can't seem to see what could possibly be null.  Any ideas?  I'm guessing the problem isn't that I'm adding something to a List in a constructor, but that I've bungled something else somewhere, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

Comment: Line 12, I've marked it with a comment on line 11.  I'll add that to my question.  I posted other relevant members of the class because I figure I would be asked to show those :)

Comment: As you have only the one constructor and checkoutProcessArguments  is private not protected why not instantiate it in the constructor? Also, if its only to be instantianted the once you can use the readonly keyword.

Comment: Also, I imagine its a transcription error as it shouldn't compile otherwise, but you seem to be missing the `new` keyword here:  private List<CheckoutProcessArgument> checkoutProcessArguments = List<CheckoutProcessArgument>();

Comment: I was about to say "oh that's a typo, I'll update."  Nope, I seriously didn't instantiate it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantianting the list in the constructor immediately before you attempt to access it. Also, if the list is to not be assigned to again you can use the `readonly` keyword. Further note that we can instantiate the list and add `stepTwoArg` to it in a single line of code.

```
private readonly List<CheckoutProcessArgument> checkoutProcessArguments;

public CustomShoppingCart()
{
    GetBaseCartSteps();

    CheckoutProcessArgument stepTwoArg = new CheckoutProcessArgument("Step2", new Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"));

    checkoutProcessArguments = new List<CheckoutProcessArgument> { stepTwoArg };

    BuildCheckoutProcess();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I appreciate the design tips as well.  I don't have any mentors where I work currently, so I've had to learn mostly through books and trial & error.

Comment: You're very welcome. Its always nice to get some positive feedback - much appreciated. Just one further note on the readonly keyword in case its new to you - it doesn't prevent you from adding new items to the list, it just means you can only instantiate it during construction of your class. Obviously, if you need to assign a new List or null to the list later just zap the keyword.